# How can I pass an innerText of HTML element as object key?

Tags: javascript

So I have an API for movies, and I have a button which should display movies of particular genre when clicked.
For example, button is something like this:

```
<span>action</span>
```

And my API url looks something like this:
[https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={api_key}&sort_by=popularity.desc&with_genres=80&page=4](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=%7Bapi_key%7D&sort_by=popularity.desc&with_genres=80&page=4)

So as you see, I should insert to with_genres param any other genre number, so I wrote a function for it:

```
function genreChoose(e){
        let genres = {
            action: 80
        }
        let url = new URL(lastUrl);
        url.searchParams.set('with_genres', genres.action)
        fetchURL(url);
    }
```

I made an object of genres, and when I click on genre `<span>` from above, it should pass innerText as object key, so a text in span and key in genres object are both "action".
I guess doing it like `url.searchParams.set('with_genres', genres.e.innerText)` doesn't work, so I'm looking for a way to pass innerText of `<span>` as object value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function genreChoose(e) {
  let genres = {
    action: 80
  };
  let url = new URL('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie');
  url.searchParams.set('with_genres', genres[e.target.innerText]);
  console.log(url);
}

button.addEventListener('click', genreChoose);
```

```html
<button>action</button>
```

Comment: it works as i wanted, thank you!